# Use existing C Code as Native Add-on in Node.js

Tags: node.js, c, static-libraries, node-gyp, node-native-addon

I have never dealed with C or C++ before, so please be gentile with me :) I want to use this C Code from this Repo as a Node Module:

https://github.com/torvalds/pesconvert

I read that this can be done with Node.Js Native Addons, but all Examples I could find were about integrating C++ Code.
I have installed node-gyp and windows-build-tools for compiling the code, but because I am using windows, the required png.h library isn't installed natively. I downloaded libpng V1.6.37 and copied it into my project in the directory `lib/lpng1637`.
Now I have to write the binding.gyp file but I can't figure out how to write it so that the library is included correctly.

```
  'targets': [
    {
      'target_name': 'pesconvert',
      'sources': [ 'pes.c',
                    'png.c',
                    'svg.c',
                    'main.c',
                    'cairo.c',
                    'pes.h'
                ],
    'include_dirs' : ['lib/lpng1637'],
    'dependencies' : ['libpng'],
    'libraries': ['-L/lib/lpng1637/libpng.a']
    },
    {
      'target_name': 'libpng',
      'type': 'static_library',
      'sources': [ 'png.h', 'pngconf.h', 'pngdebug.h', 'pnginfo.h', 'pngpriv.h', 'pngstruct.h', 'example.h', 'png.c', 'pngerror.c', 'pngget.c',
      'pngmem.c', 'pngpread.c', 'pngread.c', 'pngrio.c', 'pngrtran.c', 'pngrutil.c', 'pngset.c', 'pngtest.c', 'pngtrans.c', 'pngwio.c', 'pngwrite.c',
      'pngwtran.c', 'pngwutil.c'
      ],
      'include_dirs' : ['lib/lpng1637']
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried so many variations and this is my latest *masterpeace*... :D I read that the reference in 'libraries' has to point to an .a file in case of a static library, but there isn't even an .a file in the directory.
So my key-question is: What do I have to write in my binding.gyp file to refer to the libpng-Library correctly?

I would be happy about every kind of hint or additional information!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! The slash wasn't supposed to be there, the correct directory is lib/lpng1637

Comment: This: `'-L/lib/lpng1637/libpng.a'` refers to the root directory `/lib` which you probably don't have on Windows. I think you would have to change that to `L./lib/` or `L../lib/`